# How to configure maven for executing test ONLY on deploy

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have maven surefire plugin on pom.xml:

```
<build> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>org.mycompany.service/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now I want maven to execute test ONLY on **deploy** goal, therefore:

1. When executing *mvn deploy* tests should run
2. When executing *mvn package* or *mvn install*, tests should not run because goals are prior to deploy

Comment: Why should a test run on deploy phase? Does not make sense. Test named classes are unit tests which should run before even packaging. If you like to have test which testing something different integration tests called will run before deploy. During deploy it's too late...

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to make this work would be to bind the surefire plugin to the deploy phase. This has drawbacks:

- The tests are run after the artifacts was installed.
- Maybe the tests break because they are not meant to be run that late in the lifecycle.
- I am not sure how to make sure that they are executed before the deployment happens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this behaviour by default, or do you want that just for you or in certain environments?

Adding `-DskipTests` to the command line is usually good enough.

I have some CLI aliases that I use on my local workstation, so I don't have to type all of it, and don't forget to add it. See e.g. for zsh: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/mvn